# In JCIP sample "Listing 5.19 Memoizer", the cache should be removed when ExecutionException happen

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

Many people read "Java Concurrency in Practice", but paste the code in here for convenience.

**5.19 Final implementation of Memoizer**:

```
public class Memoizer<A, V> implements Computable<A, V> {
    private final ConcurrentMap<A, Future<V>> cache = new ConcurrentHashMap<A, Future<V>>();
    private final Computable<A, V> c;

    public Memoizer(Computable<A, V> c) {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public V compute(final A arg) throws InterruptedException {
        while (true) {
            Future<V> f = cache.get(arg);
            if (f == null) {
                Callable<V> eval = new Callable<V>() {
                    public V call() throws InterruptedException {
                        return c.compute(arg);
                    }
                };
                FutureTask<V> ft = new FutureTask<V>(eval);
                f = cache.putIfAbsent(arg, ft);
                if (f == null) {
                    f = ft;
                    ft.run();
                }
            }
            try {
                return f.get();
            } catch (CancellationException e) {
                cache.remove(arg, f);
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                throw LaunderThrowable.launderThrowable(e.getCause());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is in catch (ExecutionException e), the following snippet should be added:

```
cache.remove(arg, f);
```

Correct?

Answer (score 1):

If `compute` is idempotent, then removing it form the cache will incur unnecessary calculations, because the result of the next call to `compute` will also be an `ExecutionException`.

If you leave `f` in the cache, the next call will run `f.get()` again, which will immediately return with an `ExecutionException` without having to actually perform the computation.

So it seems more efficient the way it is.

Note that one would expect `compute` to be idempotent: it makes no sense to cache the result if it could change in the future.

Comment: So if `compute` is not idempotent, remove `f` from cache is reasonable. And a better way I think is to check the cause of `ExecutionException` to decide the policy.

Answer (score 1):

Per JCIP (p. 106):

> ...`Memoizer` removes the `Future` from the cache if it detects that the computation was cancelled; it might also be desirable to remove the `Future` upon detecting a `RuntimeException` **if the computation might succeed on a future attempt.**

(Emphasis added.)

If not, there's no point, as [assylias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20610488/27358) says above.